# jquery ui slider pips

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Is there a way to color the pips in between the selected elements range slider using jQuery ui Slider Pips plugin? I see with the plugin you can color just about anything accept for in between the selected elements. Just seeing if anyone has figured it out yet.

Comment: Hey, currently there's no built-in way of doing this. But you could visit the issue tracker on Github and ask for it as a feature! :)

Answer (score 0):

Added this functionality, hope it is helpful for you! :)
You can now style the pips that are in range with the class:

```
.ui-slider-pips .ui-slider-pip-inrange {}
```

Best, Simon.

https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/commit/281d8dea02aae3aefe39ecfa9da7f3bafd856879